# Target middle child of multiple 3 column layouts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, sass

I have an array of objects that contain details that I want to render to the DOM

```
searches.content.map((search, i) => {
   //....logic done here
   return <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
)}
```

I have the following CSS to render a row of 3 columns, so there will be 3 `SavedSearchBox`'s in each row.

```
.SavedSearchBox {
   width: 33.33333333%;
   border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   float: left;
}
```

I want to target the middle column in each row to add horizontal margin, although I am not sure how?

Also, considering that the returned markup will not always be divisible by 3, so managing the cases where say the total return is 10 or 11, I want to add margins there too.

I'm happy to hear any JS solutions (please no jQuery as I am using React and would prefer not to have to use jQuery) or CSS/SASS solutions.

Essentially I want the following...

```
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
```

and for the cases of not being divisible by 3

```
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
       | margin | margin |    
        -------- -------
```

and

```
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
| no margin | margin | no margin |
 ----------- -------- -----------
            | margin |    
             -------
```

I have a [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqgm59yf/22/) to test it out, for the css at least.

Comment: Why not use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead?

Comment: Taking into account @BenM 's comment you could use the justify-content combined with the `flex-shrink` parameter.

Comment: I had been considering using flexbox but was worried about support for IE9 which we have to support, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

It actually sounds like you have an X-Y problem, and you can use Flexbox to achieve this as follows:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 -1.5%;
}

.container .SavedSearchBox {
  background: whiteSmoke;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 1.5%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
  <div class="SavedSearchBox">search.title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this would add margin-left to the 1st column in a row and margin-right to the 3rd column in a row. I only want the margin applied to the 2nd column in a row. Is this easily achievable?

Comment: Sure, just add a negative margin to `.container`.